# How to get the question title for reputation history entries?

Tags: support, api-v2, reputation, api-v2.1

I'm trying to implement a simple rep list, much like as seen on Stack Exchange sites.

What I would like is to get three things: **the rep change amount, type of change, and question title.**

However, the [reputation changes API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-full-reputation-history) gives me only the rep change & type, and I'm left in the dark as to the question title.

How should I go about getting the associated title for a given rep change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a two-step process if [the `/posts/{ids}` path](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids) returned `title`, but it doesn't.  Since [the `/answers/{ids}` path](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids), *does* return title (with an optional filter setting), then it should be easy-ish for `/posts/{ids}` to do so as well.  Perhaps this would be a good **feature request**?

Anyway, as it stands now, you must do this in pages and in 3 steps per page.  Here's the pseudocode:

1. **Get the first page of reputation entries.**  Fortunately, these *seem* to be sorted by date in descending order.
   Set the `pagesize` to it's maximum value for this path (100).

   For example, call:

   [/2.1/me/reputation-history/full?page=1&pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow&filter=!9j_cPmQ8n](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-full-reputation-history#page=1&pagesize=100&filter=!9j_cPmQ8n&site=stackoverflow)

   and get results like:

   ```
   {
     "total": 4284,
     "page_size": 100,
     "page": 1,
     "type": "reputation_history",
     "items": [
       {
         "user_id": 331508,
         "creation_date": 1375825981,
         "post_id": 3657953,
         "reputation_change": 5,
         "reputation_history_type": "post_upvoted"
       },
       {
         "user_id": 331508,
         "creation_date": 1373713575,
         "post_id": 17615370,
         "reputation_change": 15,
         "reputation_history_type": "answer_accepted"
       },
       // etc., etc.
     ],
     "quota_remaining": 9993,
     "quota_max": 10000,
     "has_more": true
   }
   ```

   These will be the user's most recent rep changes (up to 100). Most of the time, it will be all you need -- unless the users scrolls down for more.
2. Collect the **`post_id`s into a semicolon-separated list.**  EG: `3657953;17615370`.
   Post ID's may be duplicated so, ideally, remove duplicates here -- to save bandwidth in the next steps.
3. **Feed those id's into the `/questions/{ids}` path**, using `pagesize=100` and `filter=!J4Lov0xb.M`.  For example:

   [/2.1/questions/3657953;17615370?pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow&filter=!J4Lov0xb.M](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#pagesize=100&ids=3657953;17615370&filter=!J4Lov0xb.M&site=stackoverflow)

   Yielding results like:

   ```
   {
     "total": 1,
     "page_size": 100,
     "page": 1,
     "type": "question",
     "items": [
       {
         "question_id": 3657953,
         "score": 8,
         "title": "How do I get the jQuery-UI version?",
         "tags": [
           "jquery",
           "jquery-ui",
           "greasemonkey"
         ]
       }
     ],
     "quota_remaining": 9953,
     "quota_max": 10000,
     "has_more": false
   }
   ```

   **Important:**

   1. If the `post_id` belongs to an answer, it will not appear in these results; that's okay.
   2. The `question_id` will match the `post_id` passed in when said `post_id` is for a question.
   3. The results may not be in the order of the id's that were passed in.
4. **Feed those id's into the `/answers/{ids}` path**, using `pagesize=100` and `filter=!FqMlbofLCbbHPWmQsFIonPgq86`.  For example:

   [/2.1/answers/3657953;17615370?pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow&filter=!FqMlbofLCbbHPWmQsFIonPgq86](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids#pagesize=100&ids=3657953;17615370&filter=!FqMlbofLCbbHPWmQsFIonPgq86&site=stackoverflow)

   Yielding results like:

   ```
   {
     "total": 1,
     "page_size": 100,
     "page": 1,
     "type": "answer",
     "items": [
       {
         "question_id": 17614067,
         "answer_id": 17615370,
         "score": 1,
         "is_accepted": true,
         "title": "addEventListener and setInterval fail silently in a Greasemonkey script",
         "tags": [
           "javascript",
           "greasemonkey",
           "setinterval",
           "addeventlistener"
         ]
       }
     ],
     "quota_remaining": 9945,
     "quota_max": 10000,
     "has_more": false
   }
   ```

   **Important:**

   1. If the `post_id` belongs to a question, it will not appear in these results; that's okay.
   2. The `answer_id` will match the `post_id` passed in when said `post_id` is for an answer.
   3. The results may not be in the order of the id's that were passed in.
5. **Combine the `title` values**, obtained in steps 3 and 4, with the reputation entries from step 1, by keying off the appropriate ID's.
6. Voilà, **done** in 5 easy steps (per page of results)!
7. **Repeat** steps 1-6 **for additional pages** of reputation entries, only on user demand.

Comment: Yeeesh, that's a ton of network activity, especially on mobile. I guess that's just how it's done, though :P

Comment: You can cut it down if we make, and they implement, that feature request.  There's no reason that I can see why `/posts/{ids}` shouldn't be able to return the title.

Comment: I'm tempted to write a server-side thing to do all that for me - but then I have scaling, etc. to deal with.

Comment: It's only 3 API calls per page, and most users will only request the first page.  Let the client App make the calls.  If your server makes them, it may bust your daily quota.  (Quota is by app and by IP.)